# Request for d'var Torah questions

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I'm thinking about posting a series of questions (in the spirit of the [mi-yodeya-series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series)) of the form, "What are some good, short divrei Torah from Parashat X?" where X is replaced with each parasha.

My motivation for this is to see some of the great divrei Torah that yodeyans have to share which normally wouldn't be answers to a question asked on this site. I think this is a justifiable question because having a d'var Torah to share at the shabbos table is something that is likely to be helpful to many people.

Anyway, I wanted to get some feedback from the community before I go ahead and post a ton of questions. Do people think it's a good idea?

Comment: I think "good" and "short" will need to be well-defined terms.

Comment: @yez why? I don't think it's the end of the world if someone posts something that's a bit longer than usual.

Comment: @Daniel because of Isaac's answer.

Answer (score 6):

I think such questions are likely to be [Too Broad](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) unless they include very well-defined criteria for filtering or sorting answers. Without those, there are literally infinite distinct, equally-valid answers to each question. Given the way you've laid out the goals of the project, I don't think well-defined criteria will be consistent with them.

More appropriate for our environment would be to set up a chat room for the purpose and solicit divrei Torah in it each week, or just do that in [V'dibarta Bam](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam).

Comment: Note http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/520/759 and http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1094/759 and http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1386/759